# Storing and referencing an immutable ordered list in a relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

**Background:** I have a database containing *parents* and *children's names* (this is a simplification of the actual data, but the analogy is close enough).

**Task:** The database has to store an *ordered list* of *children's names* for each *parent*.

**Assumptions:**

1. The database will contain millions of parents, possibly more.
2. Parents typically have no more than to 4 or 5 children, but rare (and even extreme) cases have to be supported as well.
3. Children's names (as well as the ordering) tends to repeat a lot. So parents should reference some `children_names_list_id` instead of keeping a copy of the actual names.
4. Children's names as well as their ordering for a particular parent are immutable.
5. Insertion of new parents will be very frequent. When a new parent is inserted with a list of his children, if such a list of names already exists in the database, the new parent should reference the existing list identifier.
6. Queries about names and their ordering should be possible (for example - *find all parents that names a child "Bob" after naming a child "Alice"*, or *find all parents that named a child "Alice", then had two more children, with the third named "Carol"* etc)

**Questions:**

1. What's the best way to store such lists? The solution should be robust and support fast parent insertions.
2. How should a parent reference the lists?

**Current (proposed) solution:**

My current approach is to have a table that maps *children names* to *integer name ids* (names are long, integers are short).
Then store name lists in the following tuples: `<list_id> <order> <name_id>` so the list table will look like this:

```
<list_id> <order> <name_id>
    1       1       123
    1       2       345
    1       3       678
    2       1       901
    3       1       123
    3       1       901
```

The example table contains three lists: [123,345,678], [901], [123,901] which might correspond to something like: ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"], ["Dave"], ["Alice", "Dave"]
The parents table will then have a `children_list_id` column that references the `list_id` column.

This solution seems to be robust, except for two issues:

1. I'm not sure whether insertions will be fast enough (looking up whether an existing list already exists seems like it could be slow), but other approaches seem to be less robust or (much) harder to query.
2. The key to the name list table is composed of both the `list_id` and the `order` columns; the parents table has to reference only the `list_id` which should be a foreign key, but since `list_id` isn't a key by itself in the list table, an additional table of lists, in which `list_id` is key is needed. This seems cumbersome.

**Alternate solution:**

The table of lists will store implicit ordering in the columns:

```
<list_id> <name_1> <name_2> <name_3> <name_4> ... <name_100>
    1        111     222     333      null
    2        444     null
    3        555     111     null
```

In this table, `list_id` will be the primary key.

The parents table will keep the `list_id` as a foreign key.

This solution is somewhat less robust (how many columns do I create? 10? 20? 50?), but makes insertions much quicker. And since the `list_id` is a key, no additional tables are needed. A possible downside however is that some queries become much more complicated since they have to reference multiple columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `list` table is over-design.  Just have a `Parents` table, a `Names` table and a `ParentChildren` table.  The `ParentChildren` table is just like your list table, except for a few details.  It would look like:

```
<ParentId> <Order> <NameId>
    1         1     123
    1         2     345
    1         3     678
    2         1     901
    3         1     123
    3         1     901
```

I don't see a particular savings to storing independent lists.  Just store the children for each parent.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. The particular savings to storing individual lists is that lists tend to repeat A LOT. So I'm not sure that this aspect of the design is over-engineered.

Comment: Just for clarity (since the parents-children) data is a simplification of the actual data - I'm talking about many millions of parents, but probably no more than several hundreds of thousands of child name lists. So the difference between parents and lists is one or two orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Malt . . . It depends on the balance of insert performance versus query performance.  Your question explicitly says:  "Insertion of new parents will be very frequent."  Having to check the list of children each time may impede insert performance.