# How to store immutable, unique, ordered, lists?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database-design, database-schema

I have an *entity* with millions of instances. Each instance has to reference an ordered list of *items*. The lists have to be unique so no list will be stored more than once. But once created, both lists and *entity* instances are immutable. There will be **far more entity instances than lists**, and the database has to support **fast insertions of *entities***.

So what's an insert-efficient, robust, way of storing **immutable**, **unique**, **ordered lists**?

---

Edit: So far, I've considered these approaches:

**1)**

`lists` table has these columns: `<list_id> <order> <item>` so if list #5 contains the elements `[10,20,30]` the table will contain:

```
5   1   10
5   2   20
5   3   30
```

The entity table will have a `item_list_id` column that references the `lists` table (it's not a foreign key since `list_id` is not a unique column in the `lists` table - *The this can be solved by adding another table with a single column that which contains all valid `list_ids`*
).

- This solution makes inserts a bit tricky
- It also places the responsibility for enforcing the uniqueness of lists on the application, which isn't great.

**2)**

`lists` table has these columns: `<list_id> <item1> <item2> <item3> ... <itemN>` so if list #5 contains the elements `[10,20,30]` the table will contain:

```
5   10   20   30
```

The entity table will have a `item_list_id` column that references the `lists` table.

- This solution is less robust since list lengths are limited (although this isn't a huge problem for me since my lists are VERY unlikely to contain more than 10 or 20 elements)
- This approach is quite horrible to query ("find all lists in which a particular item appears" has to specify each and every column), and a nightmare to map using an ORM.
- Insertions of new entities is not too bad since my lists are typically 4-5 items long, so I can probably index the first few columns.
- Enforcement of uniqueness is still in the hands of the application.

**3)**

Use solution #1, but replace the meaningless `list_id` with a hash (say SHA-1) on the list in serialized form.

- This way uniqueness is more strictly enforced since lists will have unique hashes
- Insertions are simpler and quicker(?)
- The data integrity enforcement is still in the hands of the application.

Comment: What have you tried or considered so far? Are you using mysql or sql-server? The design is quick likely to be very different in those two.

Comment: @SeanLange I've added some possible approaches I thought of to the question. Regarding the server - I'd prefer something that doesn't rely on a unique feature of one particular product, but if I find a solid solution that works for only one of them, I'll use that one.

Comment: Sadly that is not possible as approach 3 is not working easily on BOTH databases you give. See, SHA 1 is alittle big for a big integer... and binary fields can not be indices. So you end up with a varchar with hex coding or something that is slow. Compromises all along. I would go with solution 1 and reuse the entity id as list id.

Comment: @TomTom Are your sure about that? I know that UUIDs are sometimes kept as BINARY(16) columns which are primary keys of tables. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122934/best-way-to-handle-large-uuid-as-a-mysql-table-primary-key

Comment: I would run away quickly from using a guid as your primary key. That is making it exceptionally wide with little to no benefit. It also means you need some other column to use as the clustered index or your fragmentation will be through the roof (99.99% with as few as 10k rows).

Comment: I would use the "extended" version of option #1 where you also create a Lists table. If you leave data integrity up to the application you are going to be fighting that battle at some point when things go wonky. You are dangerously close to one of the design pitfalls known as preoptimization. That is you are making nonstandard design decisions to help performance for a performance problem that does not yet exist. Don't over complicate this and follow standard normalization. You will be glad you did in the long run.

Comment: @SeanLange even in the extended option #1, data integrity is in the hands of the application. The "extension" only makes sure that list_ids don't repeat, it doesn't guarantee the uniqueness of the lists themselves.

Comment: Can't you add a unique constraint? Are are you saying you don't want to have two lists that contain the exact same values?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes. I don't want to have two lists that contain the same values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing and referencing an immutable ordered list in a relational database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849370/storing-and-referencing-an-immutable-ordered-list-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: @Jenn Yeah, both questions were asked by me. But they're not exactly duplicates. Although my goal is the same, in the previous version of the question I didn't put an emphasis on the uniqueness constraint, and the proposed answer proposes duplicating lists.

Comment: @Malt it seems to me that the same answer will solve both of these questions-which is how we define duplicates. Though you have rephrased the question, I personally didn't see much of a difference.

Comment: So why not create something to help determine if a propsed (about to be inserted) list is in fact unique? That could very easily be part of the insert procedure. Seems you are putting way too much effort into something that is pretty easy to deal with.

Comment: @SeanLange that's exactly what I'm planning on doing, but this means that my application is responsible for enforcing the correctness of the data model, not the database. One of the main ideas behind database design (or actually schema design) is that the schema itself should enforce the constrains of the data model. This way buggy applications are less likely to create invalid data.

Comment: That is true but you are talking about a complex result set, not just a unique constraint. If you really that concerned about it add a check for the uniqueness of the list in an insert trigger and raise an error if the entire is duplicated. Using an insert procedure with a check should be more than sufficient imho but the trigger would ensure it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid having duplicate lists you will need to use Relational Division inside a trigger.

See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

and

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/what-is-the-name-of-this-type-of-query-and-what-is-an-efficient-example